# socket.gethostbyaddr giving different returns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7.9 and while trying to use [socket.gethostbyaddr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr), I found some perplexing behavior.

My local computer has a public ip, let's say 111.111.111.111. If I use on a remote computer:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyaddr('111.111.111.111')[0]
```

I get `'mycomputer.com'`. However, using the same command on my local computer (or using 127.0.0.1 instead of my public ip), I instead get `'MYCOMPUTER.com'`. Why is there a difference in capitalization?

Comment: According to [RFC 4343](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4343#section-2) domain names are case-insensitive, so returned case doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Well it makes a difference for string comparison in python. I'm currently just doing socket.gethostbyaddr('111.111.111.111')[0].lower(), but it's a little confusing, especially since on python 2.7.3 this doesn't happen at all.

Answer (score 2):

`gethostbyaddr` will also query the hosts file - `/etc/hosts` on Linux; Windows has an equivalent at %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (location may vary with older versions of Windows)

From the remote computer, `gethostbyaddr` will be doing a DNS lookup and getting mycomputer.com. On your local computer it is probably getting the answer from your hosts file, which contains an upper case version of your hostname.

Comment: My hosts file is currently just a sample: 
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost